# SSIS How to map multiple parameters to oledb source when access mode is SQL Command?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

****My Oledb source code is-**
**When adding second parameter it overrides first. how to solve?****

```
    IDTSComponentMetaData100 Source = PopulateEtlDataSourceDetailDFT.ComponentMetaDataCollection.New();
    Source.ComponentClassID = "DTSAdapter.OleDbSource";
    CManagedComponentWrapper srcDesignTime = Source.Instantiate();
    srcDesignTime.ProvideComponentProperties();
    Source.Name = "OLEDB Source";
    //Assigning Connection manager
    Source.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].ConnectionManagerID = Config.ID;
    Source.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].ConnectionManager = DtsConvert.GetExtendedInterface(Config);
    // Set the custom properties of the source.
    srcDesignTime.SetComponentProperty("AccessMode", 2);

    Guid variableGuid = new Guid(ETLSourceRunId.ID);
    String ParamProperty = @"""@OrganizationName"",{" + variableGuid.ToString().ToUpper() + @"};";
    srcDesignTime.SetComponentProperty("ParameterMapping", ParamProperty);
    Guid variableGuid1 = new Guid(Parent_ETLSourceRunId.ID);
    String ParamProperty1 = @"""@SourceRunID"",{" + variableGuid.ToString().ToUpper() + @"};";
    srcDesignTime.SetComponentProperty("ParameterMapping", ParamProperty1);       

    srcDesignTime.SetComponentProperty("SqlCommand","EXEC [dbo].[USP_GetCustomerEtlSourceDetailRecordSet] @OrganizationName=?,@SourceRunID=?");        
    srcDesignTime.AcquireConnections(null);
    srcDesignTime.ReinitializeMetaData();
    srcDesignTime.ReleaseConnections();
```

**1. How to add multiple parameters to oledb source? and

 2. how to add project parameters to oledb source?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm no pro at c#, but:

```
Guid variableGuid = new Guid(ETLSourceRunId.ID);
String ParamProperty = @"""@OrganizationName"",{" + variableGuid.ToString().ToUpper() + @"};";
srcDesignTime.SetComponentProperty("ParameterMapping", ParamProperty);
Guid variableGuid1 = new Guid(Parent_ETLSourceRunId.ID);
String ParamProperty1 = @"""@SourceRunID"",{" + variableGuid.ToString().ToUpper() + @"};";
srcDesignTime.SetComponentProperty("ParameterMapping", ParamProperty1);
```

2nd from last line:

```
String ParamProperty1 = @"""@SourceRunID"",{" + variableGuid.ToString().ToUpper() + @"};";
```

shouldn't it be **variableGuid1.ToString().Upper()** and not *variableGuid.ToString().Upper()* since you're assigning the value as:

```
Guid variableGuid1 = new Guid(Parent_ETLSourceRunId.ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using SQL command from variable as data access mode. Create an variable as string and set  it's value to your SqlCommand. If you SqlCommand needs multiple parameters, then again create variables to store those values and use these variables in SqlCommand variable value.

You can follow [this](http://bisherryli.com/2012/01/27/ssis-107-parameterized-query-in-ole-db-data-source-parameter-information-cannot-be-derived-from-sql-statements-with-sub-select-queries/) article to start with.

Steps

1) Create variable for SqlCommand

```
strVarSqlCommand = "EXEC [dbo].[USP_GetCustomerEtlSourceDetailRecordSet] @OrganizationName=strVarOrgName ,@SourceRunID=strVarSrcRunId"
```

2) create variables to refer in Sqlcommand variable

```
strVarOrgName = "XXX"
strVarSrcRunId="YYY"
```

As per your requirement, you can set values to these variable as hard coded or dynamically as well.

3) Use `strVarSqlCommand`  variable in ole db source where data access mode is command with variable